# how to use the return value in a completion handler?

Tags: swift, function, completionhandler

I'm trying to understand better the closures in swift and I've tried to create a silly function with a completion handler that returns a value but this value goes nowhere...

here's what I did..

```
func productToString(num: Int,num2: Int,completion: (Int)->String){

    let result = num * num2

    completion(result)
}




let numberToString = productToString(num: 3, num2: 6) { (res) -> String in

    return "string:\(res)"

}


print(numberToString) // print statement prints ()
```

when I tried to save this return value in a variable it returned just a pair of curvy brackets.

how should I use this return value?

Comment: productToString has no return value, the value is `Void`. The concept of completion callbacks is asynchronicity. The completion callback can be called much later than your `print`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're returning the value into the `productToString` function but not doing anything else with it.

```
func productToString(num: Int,num2: Int,completion: (Int)->String){

    let result = num * num2

    completion(result) // <--- Your return value ends up here
}
```

If you want to print the result you have to return it again out of the `productToString` function.

```
func productToString(num: Int,num2: Int,completion: (Int)->String) -> String {

    let result = num * num2

    return completion(result)
}
```

Sidenote: The empty brackets that are printed are an empty tuple which is equivalent to `Void` in Swift.